# Python: "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" tried to troubleshoot but doesn't work

Tags: python

When I run my code even though I see nothing wrong
Please help

```
def savings_tracker():
 input("This program will tracker your savings progress. (Press Enter to Continue)")
 goal = input("What are you trying to save for?")
 final_savings_amount = float(input("What is the total amount of money needed to each your goal"))
 monthly_savings = float (input("What is your monthly savings?"))
 current_savings = float(input("What have you saved so far?"))

 month_to_reach_goal = (final_savings_amount-current_savings)/monthly_savings

 month_to_reach_goal = math.ceil(month_to_reach_goal)

 print("The time it will take to get to your goal of",  goal, "is", month_to_reach_goal, "months!")
 print("Your getting there! Keep on saving!")
```

Comment: This doesn't show how to run the code...

Comment: Also, when I copied this into my console, I got no errors

Comment: Likely your `def` was not in the right indentation level.  Indents are important in Python.  Make sure your codes are properly indented.  As it stands this would be treated as a typo, which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common practice to use 4 spaces for indentation. See official recommendation [(PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

That should give you something like :

```py
def savings_tracker():
    input("This program will tracker your savings progress. (Press Enter to Continue)")
    goal = input("What are you trying to save for?")
    final_savings_amount = float(input("What is the total amount of money needed to each your goal"))
    monthly_savings = float (input("What is your monthly savings?"))
    current_savings = float(input("What have you saved so far?"))

    month_to_reach_goal = (final_savings_amount-current_savings)/monthly_savings

    month_to_reach_goal = math.ceil(month_to_reach_goal)

    print("The time it will take to get to your goal of", goal, "is", month_to_reach_goal, "months!")
    print("Your getting there! Keep on saving!")
```

Please consider a minimal example next time since this code is quite irrelevant to this particular indentation problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work for you:

```
import math
def savings_tracker():
    input("This program will tracker your savings progress. (Press Enter to Continue)")
    goal = input("What are you trying to save for? ")
    final_savings_amount = float(input("What is the total amount of money needed to each your goal "))
    monthly_savings = float (input("What is your monthly savings ?"))
    current_savings = float(input("What have you saved so far? "))

    month_to_reach_goal = (final_savings_amount-current_savings)/monthly_savings

    month_to_reach_goal = math.ceil(month_to_reach_goal)

    print(f"The time it will take to get to your goal of {goal} is {month_to_reach_goal} months!")
    print("You're getting there! Keep on saving!")

savings_tracker()
```

Input:

```
This program will tracker your savings progress. (Press Enter to Continue)
What are you trying to save for? a house
What is the total amount of money needed to each your goal 250000
What is your monthly savings? 6000
What have you saved so far? 50000
```

Output:

```
The time it will take to get to your goal of a house is 34 months!
You're getting there! Keep on saving!
```

Comment: And this answers the question about the `IndentationError` how?

Comment: Where did i state that?

Comment: I assumed if you write an answer you would have tried to answer what was asked. What is the point of writing an answer that doesn't tackle the question? It's like somone asking "I have a red blinking light in my car and can't find out why. Can you help me to find the reason?" and you say: "Buy a new car".